# Choosing sound codec for network (c/c++)

Tags: c, compression, audio, codec

I'am imnplementing real-time sound (voice) recording and transferring to another point in my application. 
I would ask who knows good codec or compression algorithm to transfer low-quality (max 32 kbit) sound data through the network. I know skype uses good compression, what codec use it?

*It should be free

I found also this codec interesting: iLBC (Internet Low Bitrate Vocoder), but not the source. Does know any links??
http://www.vocal.com/speech_coders/ilbc.html

Thank you.

Comment: What are your license requirements?

Answer (score 3):

One popular answer is [Speex](http://www.speex.org/). Its not the highest quality codec available, but free to use and implement.

Skype's codec is proprietary.

If you can cut the sample rate, you can also use uLaw or aLaw, which have very little processing overhead.